# Executing script on a UNIX server from PowerShell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a PowerShell script hosted in Windows Server 2008 R2. This script need to invoke a UNIX script residing in a UNIX server. After completion of execution of script it must return the output to the calling script. (PowerShell Script). I am implementing it in highly secured servers. Hence cannot use third party built tools/Libraries unless they are authenticated and approved by standards. If there is any standard library which I can make use of and accomplish this task will be appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "native" way to do it that I'm aware of.

The most secure method I can think of offhand which will be accepted by your review board is to use [`ssh`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1) with keys for authentication. Yes, you'll have to acquire & install an SSH client for Windows, but if your servers are "highly secured" then your security people should be *very* happy to hear that you want to use SSH. SSH should already be running on the UNIX servers.

You can use `ssh` to execute any command on the remote system (that you're authorized to execute) instead of creating a login shell simply by appending the command to the end of the `ssh` command line (as described by the link above).